# Логирование ошибок Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый вечер, перенес проект на laravel 5 с одного localhost на другой.
Перестало работать.
Ниже сам контроллер

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Tour;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;


class MainController extends BaseController
{
    public function getIndex(){
        return view("tour");
    }

}
```

Так не работает и сервер не отдает вообще ничего. Страница пустая, даже ошибок нет.
Если переписать так:

```
public function getIndex(){
    echo 1;
}
```

То как и должно прилетает единица.
Собственно вопрос, где посмотреть лог файла с ошибками и почему прилетает полностью пустая страница?

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо всем, оказалось что права на папку storage нужно было поставить.
На винде работало,а на убунте перестало из за прав на папку

Answer (score 0):

А у тебя есть файл tour.blade.php?

Попробуй

```
public function getIndex(){
    return "tour";
}
```

А логи здесь посмотреть storage / logs

И нам покажи если не разберешься тогда что-то конкретнее скажем. 
А сейчас похоже что шаблона нет, либо он пустой

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте включён ли режим отладки, подробней тут: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration

Файлы логов расположены в: {папка проекта}/storage/logs

P.S. Если бы показали код вьюхи, то возможно было проще ответить.